# how upgrade to XML_Parser2?

Tags: php, pear

I have PEAR library installed. Now I am upgrading my PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4

With 5.4 some functions of PEAR lib gives deprecated warning.

e.g. PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php give

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Redefining already defined constructor for class XML_Parser in /usr/share/pear/XML/Parser.php on line 227
```

My installed PEAR/XML/ have support for XML_Parser2 as well which fixes all issues for PHP upgrading

But it requires me to make changes in an already installed PEAR package, like I need to change in PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php and make it use Parser2.php instead Parser.php.

Parser2.php has support for PHP 5.4.

**My question is can I make changes in PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php. or it will violate some rule.
Or Any other solution?**

Comment: which rule? the license allows you modifications, if you retain the copyright notice. You can can make changes to PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php, but you should reapply your changes (patch), after you run `pear upgrade XML_Serializer` (or apt, yum, ... - if you have used a distro packagemanager to install it). You could also provide a patch at http://pear.php.net (or fork the package  https://github.com/pear )

Answer (score 2):

> My question is can I make changes in PEAR/XML/Unserializer.php. Or it will violate some rule. Or Any other solution?

I think the best idea is that you port your code using the supported version of the library, that is using [*`XML_Parser2`*](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Parser2/) as you write this solves all your issues.

If there is something missing in *`XML_Parser2`* but you have it in the previous and now likely unsupported version, you should port it to the new version and provide a patch - but as @pce already wrote there is no obligation for that. The pear [package `XML_Parser`](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Parser/) is under a lax permissive free software license.

The problem you describe here as been reported in the issue tracker already about a year ago, you might want to follow the issue:

- [Bug #19363 - PHP 5.4 incompatibility](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19363)

As the package is not maintained any longer, I doubt that there will be much traction, but you can always jump in your own. So better check if you can't follow the suggested upgrade path to *`Pear_XML2`*.

As you can see this is less about violating some rules but more about you finding what works for you.